# Azure Speech Translation: How to activate the recognition only when speech is detected?

Tags: javascript, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I’m currently working on a live translation web app allowing multiple participants to use the [Azure Speech Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-translation) and share their transcriptions in multiple languages.

I don’t want to be billed for the number of participants X the duration of a meeting. Hence the question: **How can I activate the recognition only when speech is detected? This way, I would only pay for the people currently speaking.**

I tried to use the `speechStartDetected` event from the [TranslationRecognizer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/translationrecognizer?view=azure-node-latest#speechStartDetected), but this event seems to fire only when the recognizer is currently recognizing (with `recognizeOnceAsync()` or `startContinuousRecognitionAsync()`)

**Is there any parameter within the Speech SDK I can use to achieve what I want? If not, what are my options?**

It might be possible to watch the audio dB level and activate the continuous recognition accordingly, but I think I will run into some problems If I try to do it this way. Ex: Once the audio level reach a certain level for a certain duration, this would trigger the `startContinuousRecognitionAsync()`, but it would miss the beginning of the speech…

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Real time [speech to text](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/) solution for live calls, With Speech to Text, you pay as you go based on the [number of hours of audio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/speech-services/) you transcribe.
Learn to view your billing invoice and usage data at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-download-azure-invoice-daily-usage-date